# Ben Sorer U'Moreh and Embarrasment

Tags: capital-punishment, embarrassment

Tosfos in the Gemarah Sota 10b writes that being מלבין את פני חבירו is a sin that one should rather give his life up for. Therefore, in the case of the Ben Sorer U'Moreh, why do we make such a big deal out of making sure that his death is public? Is this not going against embarrassing someone?

Comment: Why ask only about Ben Sorer U'Moreh?

Comment: Off the top of my head, it's the only case where we make something such a public deal

Comment: It is also generally forbidden to kill others, yet we execute the Ben Sorer Umoreh.

Comment: @Bochur613 ??? How is it different than any other execution?

Comment: @DoubleAA There are only a few cases where the Torah says "and all of Israel should hear."

Comment: What about sota?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Mishnayos in Sanhedrin (don't have the place on me now) say that when Beis Din would kill someone, they would hang his body for a split second so as not to embarrass the person who was killed. Here, we make a big deal about it.

Comment: @Bochur613 I think even the *ben sorer u'moreh*'s body would only be hanged briefly.

Comment: @loewian _hung_. The corpse was already dead.

Comment: @DoubleAA touche.

Answer (score 4):

במקום שיש חילול השם - אין חולקין כבוד לרב - "In an instance where there is desecration of G-d's name, we don't allot honor to a Rabbi". Humans who have debased themselves to the levels of animals (including the *ben sorer umoreh*) and have committed capital crimes, are judged by the Torah as having forfeited, to some degree, their right to a certain level of human dignity. (It's also worth noting that according to one opinion in the gemara, the laws of the *ben sorer umoreh* are theoretical ones that teach a lesson, but were never and will never actually be practiced.) Regardless, the only absolute in the Torah is, arguably, the ban on idolatry. All other values have scenarios where they are trumped by other competing values.

Comment: +1 I like your answer very much, where can i learn more on this subject

Comment: @hazoriz Thanks. Regarding which aspect are you interested? (There are several topics touched upon.)

Comment: 1. "debased" and 2. "human dignity"

Comment: @hazoriz  Not sure what more to add.  If you're hebrew's good enough, you might find some of the references cited here useful: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/28793 . Also, there are probably some relevant midrashim regarding the barley-based korban of the sotah.  You may also want to see the gemaras in Sanhedrin regarding the garb of those stoned to death.

Comment: Thank you This https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.45a.9 , to me it seems dignity is a main aspect of Judaism it can be seen almost every were in the torah, but you are the first who (i saw) clearly speaks about it, where did you get it from (yourself, your teacher, a book)?

Comment: @hazoriz I think as you said it ties to a main aspect of Judaism and is at least implicit in many sources including the Pentateuch itself.

Comment: do you know of others who recognized this?

Comment: @hazoriz Off the top of my head, not specifically.  But I believe it comes up a lot (e.g. with most if not all cases of punishments described in Jewish sources).

Comment: I +1ed the answer for others, but it seems totally wrong, THe problem that BSu"M did no public desecration! Just like one who eats on YK. He 1. did not follow his parents - not a PD 2. Stole his father's money - neither 3. eat meat and wine - same here. Much worse - the GM says **he's not killed for what he did**, but what he might become!

Answer (score 0):

Double's right, this is true for all executions, and it's worse for Ben SU"M because he's executed for "**something he didn't do, but for something he might become**" as the Gemmorah says.

The point of **public executions is explicitly commanded in the Torah** so there's no much what we can do against. We can resolve it in different ways but the decree of the Torah remains:

> וְהָאִישׁ אֲשֶׁר־יַעֲשֶׂה בְזָדוֹן לְבִלְתִּי שְׁמֹעַ אֶל־הַכֹּהֵן הָעֹמֵד לְשָׁרֶת שָׁם אֶת־ה"א אוֹ אֶל־הַשֹּׁפֵט וּמֵת הָאִישׁ הַהוּא וּבִעַרְתָּ הָרָע מִיִּשְׂרָאֵל׃
> וְכָל־הָעָם יִשְׁמְעוּ וְיִרָאוּ וְלֹא יְזִידוּן עוֹד׃
>
> Should a man act presumptuously ... that man shall die. Thus you will sweep out evil from Israel: **And all the people will hear and be afraid and will not act presumptuously again.**

---

THere are two ways of explaining it:

1. The public execution IS a humiliation: then it can be seen as a part of the punishment. As we hold that a humiliation as the suffer can ease one's punishment.
2. The public execution IS not considered a humiliation by the Torah (de-jure). So the question is closed.